# User Registration Form

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm studying PHP, PDO and MySQL by myself and i'm stucked here, trying to make an advanced login system. This part below is the "**register.php**":

All apparently is going well untill we reach the **INSERT** part, because nothing happens.

I'm designer and i like everything  clean, what is not the case of my code, so if one of you guys help me giving tips on how to clean my code i'll be very thankfull :)

I'm Brazillian, so some text are portuguese, but i think i don't need to translate just because they are only usual alert messages followed by the code.

```
<?php

require('include/core.php');
require('include/func.php');

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    //Information
    $user = htmlentities($_POST['user']);
    $pass1 = $_POST['pass1'];
    $pass2 = $_POST['pass2'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $register_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $email_token = md5(uniqid(rand(),1));
    $user_level = "normal";
    $ip = get_ip();

    //Validation
    if(!isset($user)) {
        echo "Você não digitou um nome de usuário";
    } else if(strlen($user) < 4) {
        echo "Digite um nome de usuário com pelo menos 3 Caractéres";
    } else if(empty($pass1)) {
        echo "Você precisa digitar uma senha.";
    } else if(empty($pass2)) {
        echo "Você precisa digitar a senha novamente, para confirmação.";
    } else if(empty($email)) {
        echo "Você precisa digitar um email.";
    } else if($pass1 != $pass2) {
        echo "As senhas não conferem.";
    } else if(filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) == false) {
        echo "Digite o email corretamente.";
    } else {

        //Checking for Existing User
        $query = $database->prepare('SELECT user, email, ip 
        FROM sk_user WHERE user = ? OR email = ? OR ip = ?');

        $query->bindParam(1, $user);
        $query->bindParam(2, $email);
       $query->bindParam(3, $ip);

        $query->execute();

        $row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);

        if($row > 0) {
            echo "Já existe um usuário com esses dados!";
        } else {

            $query2 = $database->prepare("INSERT INTO sk_user(user, pass, email, register_date, email_token, user_level, ip) VALUES (:user, :pass, :email, :register_date, :email_token, :user_level, :ip");

            $query2->bindParam(':user', $user);
            $query2->bindParam(':pass', $pass2);
            $query2->bindParam(':email', $email);
            $query2->bindParam(':register_date', $register_date);
            $query2->bindParam(':email_token', $email_token);
            $query2->bindParam(':user_level', $user_level);
            $query2->bindParam(':ip', $ip);

            $query2->execute();

    }

}

?>
```

Comment: Add `$database->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` right after the connection is opened, see if it yields anything, including error reporting placed at the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Answer (score 2):

There is a little mistake in the INSERT query, the following:

```
    $query2 = $database->prepare("INSERT INTO sk_user(user, pass, email, register_date, email_token, user_level, ip) VALUES (:user, :pass, :email, :register_date, :email_token, :user_level, :ip");
```

Should be replaced by:

```
    $query2 = $database->prepare("INSERT INTO sk_user(user, pass, email, register_date, email_token, user_level, ip) VALUES (:user, :pass, :email, :register_date, :email_token, :user_level, :ip)");
```

The last parenthesis of the query is missing ;)

Also, why don't you use the same structure for the two prepare statements?

Answer (score 1):

The following line has a missing closing bracket `)`
to close off the opening bracket `(` in `$query2 = $database->prepare(...`

where it ends in `:user_level, :ip");`

```
$query2 = $database->prepare("INSERT INTO sk_user(user, pass, email, register_date, email_token, user_level, ip) VALUES (:user, :pass, :email, :register_date, :email_token, :user_level, :ip");
```

Change it to: (the end of the following line reads as `:user_level, :ip)");`

```
$query2 = $database->prepare("INSERT INTO sk_user(user, pass, email, register_date, email_token, user_level, ip) VALUES (:user, :pass, :email, :register_date, :email_token, :user_level, :ip)");
```

---

Add `$database->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` right after the connection is opened, including error reporting placed at the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` which helps to debug code.

It would have signaled the syntax error.

---

***An important note regarding password storage:***

I noticed you may be storing passwords in plain text, which is not recommended and is unsafe to do.

Use [**CRYPT_BLOWFISH**](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/36471) or PHP 5.5's [`password_hash()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function.
For PHP < 5.5 use the [`password_hash() compatibility pack`](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

If this is for a LIVE site, **do not** store passwords in plain text, it's just a matter of time before your Website gets hacked.

I've seen too many cases here on Stack regarding this matter, because of people doing just that.